# Percentage/Mixture data with many zeros

Tags: count-data, predictor, zero-inflation

My dependent variable is continuous.

My independent variables can be looked at in two ways. In the first, they are a bunch of count data with a large cluster at zero. In the second way, we can consider them as percentage variables that sum to 1 for each observation, again with a mass at zero.

I would like to log-transform them, but the zeros create an obvious issue. I am not keen on doing log(x+epsilon) for obvious reasons and log(x+1) doesn't appeal to me either.

Another thought is to have a series of binary variables that determine =0 or >0, as well as the count or percentage data to go with it. I'm still not sure how this can play out with a logarithm though.

I am also curious if there is an entirely different sort of regression from OSL that could be potentially useful on this sort of data.

Comment: What are the "obvious reasons" you don't want to add a small value to the numbers? Why do you want to transform them anyway? Why would you need a "different sort of regression"? What is the actual problem here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure log(x+epsilon) will just create large outliers since log(small_number) = large negative. I want to take a logarithm though because I want to linearize the effect of the independent variable on the dependent variable.